# VST Plug-In not showing up in Ableton Live 11 (MAC Big Sur)

Tags: vst, ableton-live

I copied the .vst3 and .component files from the VST installer to the "System" paths, "/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3" and "../Components". I also allowed the files to be accessed thru Security option on the MAC, and I also removed the "quarantine" flag from the .vst3 and .component files. I have gone to the Preferences->Audio settings, and enabled System VST3; Rescan does nothing.   I also tried setting Custom VST3 to the same path; same result.  Restarting Ableton, no evidence of the plugin shows up in Plug-Ins or elsewhere.  My MAC is an older Intel Dual Core i5 running "Big Sur".  All the built-in Ableton stuff works great, but I just can't get any VSTs to install. (I tried several, same procedure, same result).  The i5 is a 64bit processor; from looking at the file Info of the .vst, since nothing is listed my understanding is that it was built for 64bit.   I'm at a loss as to what to check next!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, problem solved.  FYI, in case anyone else trips on similar issues.  The installation package of the vst contained an IMPROPERLY NAMED file.  The offender was .vst3.vst.   After having successfully installed a completely different plugin, I checked the /library/audio/plug-ins/vst3 folder, and saw that ITS correct type was simply ".vst3".  So I renamed the offender, and voila!  It now shows up and works in Ableton Live.  ARRRGH!